# How to integrate Pidgin with Ubuntu "Online Accounts" (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, pidgin

The title says it all. How can I integrate Pidgin with the default "Online Accounts" that comes with Ubuntu 14.04, just like Empathy does.

Pidgin already shows up in the "envelop" icon in the menu bar, but I still need to configure my accounts in Pidgin, I want to use the ones that I already configured in "Online Accounts".

Comment: Online accounts are mostly for gnome core apps, doubt you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do so without or with plug-ins. Pidgin doesn't communicate with any external configuration and authentication data providers and uses its own database only.

Answer (score 0):

For Pidgin to look up your account details externally, Pidgin has to be developed for it. It's possible that you could do that with a plugin, but I don't know if such a plugin exists.